# How javafx process events when target is already removed from scene graph

Tags: java, concurrency, javafx

JavaFX's event queue may contain more than one event. And handler for preceding one may remove from scene graph some node that is needed to build path for a succeeding event. It's even possible to remove event target during event capturing phase before event bubbling phase.

How would JavaFX system behave under such conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I've build simple testing scene. It is turned out that events actually are delivered to parent even if child is removed from scene just after firing event. I suppose that building event path is done immediately without delaying to event loop.